# How to add ForEach Loop from Lookup Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am developing a pipline which i need to get records from a CSV file and run through a ForEach loop to read line by line and pass each line for POST request. In ForEach loop how do i read line by line and send that line to next web activity. Following is a screenshot of my Pipeline,

[image: Image of the Pipeline]

I managed to read data from CSV file then i am expecting to send line by line to a POST request.

Any Support would be appreciated !

Comment: You can try putting the Web activity "inside" the ForEach activity; currently, it's outside of the ForEach.  You may be able to click and move the existing Web activity into it, or you can click the plus (+) button inside the ForEach to create a new Web activity.  When the activity is inside the ForEach, you should be able to use the @item() variable to get each iteration.  I haven't tried this on a CSV, but hopefully each @item() will be a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup activity will give the output as JSON array like below from csv when you uncheck the **First row only** option in it.

[image]

You need to pass this array to ForEach like this.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

[image]

Inside ForEach activity, use your web activity to POST the data. If you want to pass the one object from the Lookup output array in each iteration, then use `@item()` in the web activity body.

If you want to pass any particular field from the object of the Lookup output array in each iteration(`col1` for example), then use `@item().<column_name>` in the web activity body.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Appreciate the support !